# What does "Now,either way,you'll get flowers the next morning" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this sentence in the sitcom The Big Bang Theory S11E12 00：02：00. Is it an American culture to send flowers to someone pregnant?
The context is here.

> Stuart：Bernadette still going stir-crazy?
>   Howard：Oh, a little. Two months of bed rest. It's kind of rough.
>   Raj：Really? That sounds great. How do I get that?
>   Leonard：You'd either have to break your hip or let Howard knock you up.
>   **Penny：Now, either way, you'll get flowers the next morning.**

Comment: Is P talking to R? And are you sure your transcription of that last sentence is accurate?  I don't know what to make of "Now". Perhaps a kind of concession.

Comment: Yes,i think Penny is talking to Raj.And i have checked the subtitle.It's correct.But i'm not sure whether the subtitle itself is right or not.Maybe it's 'nah' or 'em'?

Comment: Bernadette is on the bed in her own house and Penny is talking to Raj.It's just before their discuss about Sheldon's wedding.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Can't recall the scene exactly, but I could see "Now" being used as a way of transitioning between conditional perfect and future perfect. Redundant and filler-y, but that's casual spoken dialogue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common give flowers to a girlfriend or to say "thank-you". It is also common to give flowers to someone who is injured and in hospital.

There may be a further joke in that giving flowers is rather old-fashioned, and giving flowers to someone that you know only from a one-night-stand might be a bit creepy, so the joke is that Howard would "knock Sheldon up" but then send flowers to show his appreciation, which would be creepy.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But i still feel confused.Is this the typical thing that Howard would do?Or is it an allusion to other films?

Comment: In early episodes Howard was very "creepy" towards women. As his relationship with Bernadette developed this aspect of his character was toned down. See  http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Howard_Wolowitz

Comment: Oh,i just remembered it because of your reminding.He used to speak with girls in foreign language.LOL.Thanks a lot!